# Can I use the new, open sourced core CLR for building cross platform applications?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

My question is that can I use the new, open sourced [core CLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) for building cross platform applications? Is it possible to implement the common business logic in C# and then use it as a library in my Android, iOS or in Linux applications?
How can I find out which types, methods, ... are implemented in the core clr?

Comment: Have you seen [xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) and [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)?

Comment: I'm not looking for the write once, run everywhere approach, rather than having a shared C# codebase, which could be exposed to the platform specific implementations. With Xamarin we've had some bad experiences, mostly because OSX 64 bit support wasn't really great and the newest APIs wasn't available. I'm sure it improved since then, though.

Comment: Right now it is only Linux and OSX for ASP.NET 5 apps.  The intention of open-sourcing it was to make it more universal, this is pretty likely to happen.  I wouldn't hold my breath for MSDN-quality documentation, always difficult with rapidly changing open source projects.  The source is the documentation :)